# Как я могу вызвать переопределенную функцию в производном классе?

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

В общем у меня есть два класса

```
class A{
public:
   virtual void foo(int a){};
   void foo(int a, int b){}:
};

class B: public A {
public:
   void foo(int a){};

   static B member;
};
```

Могу ли я как то вызвать функцию foo() у объкта класса B? Я пытаюсь вызвать вот так

```
B::member.foo(2);
```

компилятор выдает ошибку, что функции с такими параметрами нет

Comment: Вам следует привести настоящий код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо его открыть - у вас функция `private`, которую вызвать вне класса нельзя.

```
class B: public A {
public:
   void foo(int a){};

   static B member;
};
```

вас спасет. См. https://ideone.com/bYhJWF

Comment: Вот что случается, при ответе на вопрос, в котором отсутствует [mcve]. Если бы в этом бала проблема, тогда была бы ошибка, что нет доступа к функции, а не что что функции с такими параметрами нет.

Comment: @user7860670 Очень может быть, что некий компилятор именно так сообщает о проблеме отсутствия доступа.

Comment: Это вряд ли. Куда вероятнее, что в вопросе написано совсем не то. Тем более что вопрос был опять отредактирован...